# Array.length vs Array.prototype.length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found that both the `Array` Object and `Array.prototype` have the `length` property. I am confused on using the `Array.length` property. How do you use it?

```
Console.log(Object.getOwnpropertyNames(Array));//As per Internet Explorer
```

outputs:

```
length,arguments,caller,prototype,isArray,
```

`Prototype` and `isArray` is usable but how do you use the `length` property?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Array` is a constructor function.

All functions have a `length` property that returns the number of declared parameters in the function definition.

Comment: Tht was a perfect ans ..Thanks dear sir

Answer (score 1):

`Array.length` is how many arguments the function `Array()` takes and `Array.prototype.length` is an instance method that gives you the length of your array. When you check `['foo'].length` you're actually checking `Array.prototype.length` with the `this` argument being your array `['foo']`

```js
var myArray = ['a','b','c']
console.log(myArray.length); //logs 3
```

Comment: I mean how to Check Array.length ..I m not talking abt the Array.prototype.length..Ok i got ,i should use it within function right?

Comment: How to check Array.length for what? Why would you possibly care about Array.length? You already know what it means. Multiple people have already explained to you what it means. You need to stop and read the answers people have provided. Maybe think a little.

Comment: See here @MaizerePathak.Nepal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length

Answer (score 0):

If you have an instance of an `Array`, it inherits all properties from the `Array.prototype` thanks to [Javascript's use of prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Take the following example:

```js
function MyClass() {
  this.foo = Math.random();
}

MyClass.prototype.getFoo = function() {
  return this.foo;
}

// Get and log
var bar = new MyClass();
console.log(bar.getFoo());
```

This declares a function (serving as the constructor) for a class. That function provides the prototype for each instance of the class. When we assign a method (`getFoo`) to that prototype, every instance of the class will have the method.

You can then call the method on an instance and it will be applied to the data that class contains. In the case of arrays, the `length` property will get the length of the array you call it on:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].length == 4; // Every array has a length
```

However, because functions behave largely like objects and may have their own properties, `Array` itself may have properties. That is what you see when using `Array.length`, which gets the number of parameters the `Array` (constructor) function expects to receive. [Every function has a `length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

Answer (score 0):

`Array.length` provides the number of declared parameters in `Array` function definition. Since Array function definition has only one `size` parameter, hence it will return 1 irrespective of your array content.

`Array.prototype.length` provides the number of elements in array data. It is dependent on the array content.

```
var arr=new Array();
console.log(Array.length);//returns 1
console.log(arr.length);//returns 0 as array has 0 elements
```