# What is the significance of the `Object.length` property on JavaScript's `Object` constructor?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for the JavaScript language's built-in global `Object` object states that

> ### Object.length
>
> > Has a value of 1.

What is the significance of this property and, additionally, why isn't `object.length` available to us in the same manner as `array.length`?

At first glance, it would seem to me that the reason for my latter question has to do with a possible confusion in the interpreter of the `length` property on the object with the dot notation method of property access/initialization.

Comment: You might like to test the value of `Array.length` (note the capital "A")...

Comment: It's a static property of the `Object` constructor function, not `Object.prototype.length` that would be inherited by all instances

Comment: related, if not duplicate: [Array.length vs Array.prototype.length](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28240173/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi – First thing I did after reading this question is to find the dupe but I could not find it.. You did it ;)

Comment: @Rayon: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Object.length%22+[js] did it for me :-)

Comment: @Bergi – Unfortunately [__Google__](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=object.length%20is%201%20javascript) failed.. May be a bad search string...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **The [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property specifies the number of arguments expected by the `function`.**

As `Object` belongs to type `function` and `length` property of function 
determines the number of arguments, `Object.length` returns the length of arguments being expected.

---

*Consider following example:*

```js
function test(a, b, c) {}
console.log(test.length);
```

And with `Object`:

```js
console.log(typeof Object);
console.log(Object.length); //returns 1
```

---

**"why isn't object.length available to us in the same manner as array.length?"**

Note that `array` is also of type `object`(Try `typeof []`) hence *"why isn't object.length available to us"* is not literally correct. If you are referring to `object-without-indices`, we read the object property using the `key` of the `object`, if there is no key as `length`, `obj.length` returns `undefined`.

Comment: If I create a random  function f1(){}, f1.length gives me 0, but why does Object.length gives one

Comment: @ajaykumar – Your `f1`, expects `0` arguments hence `f1.length` is `0`, but `function Object` does expect ___`1`___ argument hence length is `1`

Comment: are you referring to implicit 'this' argument incase of Object Fn

Comment: I am still in a confusion how Object.length expects 1. I would appreciate if could throw some more light.

Comment: @ajaykumar – You are reading it wrong, it is `Function.length`, `Object` is of type `Function`. Consider this example, `parseInt.length`, it returns `2` and the reason is [___`parseInt()`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) expects `2` [_parameters/arguments_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)