# Array.length vs arrayinstance.length in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a bit confused by the `Array.length` property (i.e. a property named `length` on the `Array` function object) and `array_instance.length` (i.e. a property named `length` on instance of array object)

[image]

So what is difference between the two `length` property and when should/shouldn't we use them?

**Edit 1:**

there is also a `length` property on `Array.prototype` object. I am so confused.

[image]

**Edit 2**

Just to paint a clearer picture, here are the different `length` properties I have found

[image]

**Edit 3**

This is one of the follow up questions I asked in the comment section, but I think the question is important to fully understanding `length` property, so I have copy-pasted here in the main section

Follow up question:

`Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty('length')` and `Array_instance.hasOwnProperty('length')` return `true`, does that mean there are two `length` properties, one on `array_instance`, one on `Array.prototype` object, with the `array_instance.length` overshadowning the `Array.prototype.length`?

Comment: Use `arrayInstance.length` when you want to measure the length of an array instance.

Comment: Great question. It always bothered me that JavaScript chose `length` over `arity` to describe this property of functions. See [*Arity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity)

Comment: Please see- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240173/array-length-vs-array-prototype-length, regarding third question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I really think a lot of the other answers have covered everything needed here, but as it seems the OP hasn't had what they see a a clear answer, I will try to set everything out, somewhat extensively - but as clearly as I can - in order to clarify. (Apologies if anyone thinks I am "stealing" their answer - I assure you that this is not the intention, and I'm deliberately not looking at them as I type this, but I've certainly read most of them and even upvoted a few.)

**Array.length**

This has already been well-covered above. `Array` is a native JS function, which you can use for creating arrays. It's less common then simply defining an array literal (and as far as I know there is no reason it would ever be preferable), but instead of `var a = [1,2,3]` you are allowed to do this:

```js
var a = Array(1,2,3);
console.log(a);
```

Note in passing that you *don't* want to do this to create a singleton array, there is an utterly mad gotcha of a special case when you supply exactly one parameter which happens to be an integer:

```js
var a = Array(5);
console.log(a);
```

Although that shows what appears to be an array of 5 `undefined` values in whatever JS console implementation SO uses, that's not actually quite what has been created (nor what is displayed in the current version of Chrome). I'm getting way off-topic but I'll refer you to [Kyle Simpson's excellent walkthrough](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch3.md#array) of the madness.

Anyway, since `Array` is a function, as others have already observed, it has a `length` property [as all functions do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length). I'm really not sure why it evaluates to `1` though - for a user-defined function it is the number of arguments the function was formally declared with, but since `Array` like all native JS functions isn't actually implemented in JS, I couldn't tell you how the implementation actually works. Clearly it *can* take any number of arguments and thus is a rather "exotic" function. I don't think that `Array.length` would ever be useful, no matter what value was arbitrarily assigned to it, but it seems that most implementations go for 1, even if the specification leaves it open. (I'm not enough of a spec devotee to know if this is actually defined in there or left up to implementations.)

**arrayinstance.length**

This is just the feature of arrays that we know and use all the time. All JS arrays get this property - note that, although it is a property rather than a method (that is, it is not a function), it nevertheless "auto-updates" as the array gets longer/shorter:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a.length);
a.push(4);
console.log(a.length);
a.pop();
a.pop();
console.log(a);
console.log(a.length);
```

Although as I said, Javascript's native constructors are not implemented in terms of JS itself, you could implement this kind of behaviour by defining a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) (at least since ES5).

**Array.prototype.length**

To fully explain what `Array.prototype` (and similar objects) is would take me deep into how Javascript's object system work. Suffice to say here that, unlike class-based languages (and JS does *not* have classes, even in ES6, despite the `class` syntax allowing us often to pretend it does), JS does not have the usual concept of "inheritance" that so-called OO languages do. In JS's version (sometimes called "prototypal inheritance"), what happens it that each object has an "internal prototype" which references some other object - and if you try to access a property on that object which it doesn't have, the JS engine will look at that "prototype object" for the property and use its value instead.

It's actually a very simple mechanism, but there are a number of things in the language which confuse this, one of them being the fact that functions (which are also objects) have a property called `prototype` - which does *not* point to the real "prototype" object which gets consulted if a nonexistent property is referenced on the function object. (A normal function `foo` has `Function.prototype` is the object that it delegates to - not `foo.prototype`.) However, if you declare a function `foo`, an object called `foo.prototype` is created - which is basically an empty, nondescript object. Its significance is that if the function `foo` is used as a "constructor" - that is, if you make an object by calling `new foo()` - `foo.prototype` will then be the object that JS will look up properties (including methods) on if any object constructed from `foo` happens to fail a property lookup.

This is why, at least in pre-ES6 code, you quite frequently saw this kind of pattern:

```js
function foo(a,b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
}

foo.prototype.add = function() {
  this.a = this.a + this.b;
}

var myFoo = new foo(1,2);

console.log(myFoo.a);

myFoo.add();
console.log(myFoo.a);

myFoo.add();
console.log(myFoo.a);

console.log(myFoo.hasOwnProperty("add"));
```

Despite appearances, `myFoo` doesn't actually have a method `add` in this example - as confirmed by the final `console.log`. When the JS engine fails to find the property though, it goes to `myFoo`'s "internal prototype", which happens to be `foo.prototype`. And that's why the method works, as it would on any object constructed from `foo`.

Anyway, this is leading up to the fact that Arrays, which could be (although almost never are) constructed by calling `new Array` (I didn't use the `new` operator above, but I could have done, this is a case where it makes no difference), therefore delegate to `Array.prototype`. All those array methods that you know and love don't "really" exist on the arrays you call them on:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
a.push(4);
console.log(a);

console.log(a.hasOwnProperty("push"));
console.log(Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty("push"));
```

So array methods only work because those methods are actually found on the `Array.prototype` object, to which all arrays delegate for property/method access if the lookup doesn't succeed on the array itself. (And this is why, if you look up any of them on MDN, the top of the page always says `Array.prototype.<method_name>`, because that's where the method "really" lives.)

A drastic demonstration of this (please DON'T do this in production code!)

```js
// you're used to doing this, and it works:
[1,2].push(3);
console.log("that went fine");

// vandalism on a grand scale!
Array.prototype.push = undefined;

// now you can'tse the "push" method anymore!
[1,2,3].push(4);
```

But I'm going to end on something of an anticlimax. The above is true for array methods - but the `length` array property *isn't* a method. As observed above, it's just a "plain" (non-function) property, which "magically" behaves somewhat like a function call. As observed in the OP, `.length` property accesses *don't* delegate as the method calls shown above do, the property exists on each array in itself.

So why does `Array.prototype` still itself have a `length` property? Well, `Array.prototype` is actually itself an array. In fact, that's not the only thing:

```js
Array.prototype.push(1);
console.log(Array.prototype);

Function.prototype();
```

notice that `Array.prototype.push(1)` ends up with `Array.prototype` being the singleton array `[1]`. So `Array.prototype` is "kind of like" the empty array (it's not exactly the same, because it has all those methods mentioned above directly accessible on the object itself, which a "normal" empty array doesn't). And with `Function.prototype`, although calling it didn't output anything, the fact that no `TypeError` was raised proves that it really *is* a function (it's actually a "no-op" function, like `function() {}`, but once again with various methods diretcly on it - the methods which every function has access to, such as `.call` and `.bind`).

Anyway, to cut the digression short, since `Array.prototype` is - as far as ordinary array properties are concerned, at least - an empty array, this explains why it has a `length` property, and why it's equal to 0.

I hope this clears things up, as well as demonstrating some of the more intriguing parts of Javascript.

Comment: Nice answer, But why in first place `Array.Prototype` is an `Array`?

Answer (score 28):

functions have a `.length` property which corresponds to how many arguments they are expecting. For example:

```js
const unary = (a) => {

}

const binary = (a, b) => {

}

console.log(unary.length);
console.log(binary.length);
```

So the Array constructor has a length of 1 because it expects one parameter to be passed to it (namely, the size of the array).

array objects also have a `.length`property, which is unrelated other than having the same name. This property says how large the array currently is.

Comment: hi Nicholas, thanks for answering the question. But just now I have found another `length` property on `Array.prototype` object, is it in any way related to `Array.length`?

Answer (score 12):

The first part has already been answered, `Array` constructor is a function and functions have a `.length` property.

For the second, `Array.prototype.length`, it's a bit more obscur...

#### `Array.prototype` is actually an Array:

```js
console.log(Array.isArray(Array.prototype)); // true
Array.prototype.push('hello'); 
console.log(Array.prototype.length); // 1
console.log(Array.prototype[0]); // "hello"
```

As to why is it an Array? Because [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) say so:

> The Array prototype object is an Array exotic objects and has the internal methods specified for such objects. It has a length property whose initial value is 0 and whose attributes are { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }..

There is also a note specifying that it is for compatibility reasons with [previous versions of the specs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4).

As to why is was designed as being an Array? I have no really strong idea...

Comment: I think suppose it was not an array then, if you do `Array.prototype.push(1)` or call any other method that is specific to an array, it would give error, maybe that is why designer made it to be an Array, what do you think?

Answer (score 6):

**Disclaimer:** 
I have tried to show how constructor and instance works in general. But in fact, they have huge difference between different constructors.

Any constructor has been set its length with the value specified by the spec. Specially most of them are set to 1:

```
Number.length // 1
Object.length // 1
Function.length // 1
Array.length // 1
// etc.
```

Similarly,

```
Array.constructor.length // 1
// etc.
```

Like @Kaiido pointed out in the comment, you can see some constructor length is set:

```
Document.length // 0
Int8Array.length // 3
Date.length // 7
```

And you may also notice the length of the instance is `undefined` as they are not set. - It's out of the scope though.

```
let d = new Date
d.length === undefined // true
```

See at the bottom for relevant references.

But when you have an instance of it, then you're creating a new value of it:

```
typeof new Array === typeof Array.prototype // true
typeof new Function === typeof Function.prototype // true
// etc.
```

So, when you use an instance it has no length value set because it has no any parameters:

```
let arr = new Array // Array.prototype
arr.length === 0 // true
```

But when you use an instance with parameter, then you have the length property with the value of parameters

```
let arr = new Array(20)
arr.length === 20 // true
let func = function(a1,a2,a3,a4){}
func.length === 4 // true
// etc.
```

---

So now, you have been wondering why the constructor has length value equal to 1?

It's because the spec has set the value to be 1 initially.

> Every built-in Function object, including constructors, has a length property whose value is an integer. Unless otherwise specified, this value is equal to the largest number of named arguments shown in the subclause headings for the function description, including optional parameters.
>
> The value of the [[Prototype]] internal slot of the Object constructor is the intrinsic object %FunctionPrototype%.
>
> Besides the length property (whose value is 1),

See these references:

[Standard built in objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects),

[19.1.2 Properties of the Object Constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-object-constructor),

[19.2.2 Properties of the Function Constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.length),

etc.

Also, you can see the prototype has length to 0, you already know it why in the preceding example.

Though, here's just a reference stating that:

[19.2.3 Properties of the Function Prototype Object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object)

And there some constructor whose length is set different. This is the out of scope of this answer. Though, here's a reference for the date constructor:

[20.3.3 Properties of the Date Constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-date-constructor)

So, it's totally up to the spec how they have been defined.

Comment: `Document.length`? 0. `Int8Array.length`? 3. `Date.length`? **7**!

Comment: But all the remaining of the answer is also factually incorrect. That typeof `Array.prototype` is `"object"` is quite normal, but that `typeof Function.prototype` is `"function"` is a special case, and the conclusion you draw from it is completely erroneous. `function MyClass() {}
MyClass.prototype = e => {};
typeof new MyClass === typeof MyClass.prototype` => false

Comment: @Kaiido I hope the updated answer fits. Please feel free to update the answer if you think is needed to be. We're just helping out each-others not anything else.

Comment: Showing `Array.constructor.length` is pretty useless given that `Array.constructor == Function` and you already presented `Function.length`.

Comment: "*when you use an instance it has no length value set because it has no any parameters*" - this makes no sense at all. It has a length, it is `0` or `20` in your examples, and it has nothing to do with function parameters whatsoever.

Answer (score 5):

#### Array.length

`Array` is constructor which means its type is `"function"`. You try the checking it console.

```
typeof Array //"function"
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

> The `length` property indicates the number of parameters expected by the `function`.

As the `Array` function expects single argument so `Array.length = 0`

#### array_instance.length

> The `length` property of an object which is an instance of type `Array` sets or returns the number of elements in that array

As we know that arrays are actually objects so objects can have properties. The property `length` is on the instance of array.
Now second question you may ask why we don't get the `length` properties of array using `Object.keys` or `for..in` loop. The answer is because this property is not `Enumerable`.

```js
let arr= [];

//this.property 'length2' will not be shown in for..in or Object.keys();
Object.defineProperty(arr,'length2',{
  value:'length2 for test',
  enumerable:false
})

//this property 'x' will be displayed in for..in loop and Object.keys()
Object.defineProperty(arr,'x',{
  value:'length2 for test',
  enumerable:true
})


console.log(Object.keys(arr)); //["x"]
```

#### Array.prototpe.length

According to the [DOCS](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.1)

> The initial value of `Array.prototype.constructor` is the standard built-in `Array`
>   The Array prototype object is itself an array; its `[[Class]]` is "Array", and **it has a length property (whose initial value is +0)** constructor

Actually `Array.prototype` is an array. And remember array is always object. So it can have properties. The methods of the Array are stored in form of `key:value`. and there is no element in that array so it `Array.prototype.length` returns `0`. If you `push()` some elements into it you will see it as array.

```js
console.log(Array.prototype.length) //0

console.log(Array.isArray(Array.prototype)) //true

//adding element to array
Array.prototype.push('x') 

console.log(Array.prototype.length) //1
```

As I explained in second parts you can hide properties of `Object` by setting `enumerable:false`. All the methods are keys of `Array.prototype` But now shown in `for..in` loops.

Comment: @Maheer you mentioned that **array_instance.length**  is a property set to `enumerable:false`  and that is why is not shown in `for..in` loops which is the expected behavior. Now, if I print an object using `console.log(object)` even non-enumerable properties are shown; if we `console.log(array_instance)` the **length** property is not shown, why and how is that?

Answer (score 2):

**Array.length**
For the number of properties in the array or the length property of an object which is an `instance of type Array` sets or returns the number of elements in that array.

**Array.prototype.length**
Inherited number of properties in the array. When you check `Array.length` you're actually checking `Array.prototype.length`